# fortran read statement not stopping

Tags: arrays, fortran

program not stopping to read "ar". help please. even after allocating that it has definite number of elements. what may be the reason? is there something a could have missed?

```
program summer_a39
    implicit none
    integer:: n, i, l, k
    integer, allocatable, dimension(:)::ar
    print*, 'Enter size of array:'
    read*, n
    allocate (ar(n))
    print*, 'Enter values:'
    read*, ar
    l=1
    3 do i=l,n-1
        if (l==n) then
        goto 4
        end if
        if (ar(i)<=ar(i+1)) then
        goto 1
        else 
        goto 2
        end if
    end do
    1 do i=l,n-1
        do while (ar(i)<=ar(i+1))
        k=k+1
        end do
        l=k
    end do
    print*, 'Increases to', l
    goto 3
    2 do i=l,n
        do while (ar(i)>=ar(i+1))
        k=k+1
        end do
        l=k
    end do
    print*, 'Decreases to', l
    goto 3 
    4 print*, 'The End'
    deallocate(ar)
    end program
```

Comment: Anyone using `goto` as illustrated here deserves the world of pain coming down the turnpike.

Answer (score 0):

Uhm... Wow... Well...

That code makes no sense at all.

I hate to say it, but you still have a lot of learning and understanding to do.

First of all: **STOP USING GOTO**. It breaks the code flow and makes reading it a mess.<sup>1)</sup>

Secondly: Even without checking, I'm confident that the `read` statement is not the reason your program hangs. It hangs between the various loops.

Even without the `goto` statements, this snippet alone is a surefire way to get the program to hang:

```
do while (ar(i)>=ar(i+1))
    k=k+1
end do
```

This loop keeps repeating for as long as `ar(i)` is larger or equal to `ar(i+1)` -- but in the body of the loop, neither value changes (only `k`, but `k` is not part of the condition). So if the condition is true *once*, it will stay true *forever*, and the loop will never ever terminate.

Then you keep jumping back to the beginning of a loop. Each time you do that, the loop starts again from scratch. Again, you never come to a conclusion.

I contemplated showing how to use subroutines to do what I think you want to do, but I thought better of it. You need a lot more time to understand what's going on, and I suggest you find some dedicated resources that teach programming.
It doesn't have to be Fortran specific, any tutorial for any procedural language will help you understand program flow, which is what you need to analyse this mess.

<sup>1)</sup> a good programmer might know when to use `goto`. You are not a good programmer yet.

Comment: the task itself requires using GOTO

Comment: What do you mean with 'the task itself requires using GOTO'? There's nothing that requires GOTO, and ridiculously few situations in which GOTO is an improvement over the alternative.

Comment: the task where you need to find monotonic sequences. so the task from the taskbook requires to use GOTO when solving this problem.

Comment: So this is an exercise, and the exercise specifically requests you to use `GOTO`?

Comment: Do a different problem then , or solve it in modern style, or probably best get a better book. I can't remember when I last used goto in a Fortran program - certainly over 10 years ago.

Comment: I've tested this challenge, and if it was meant to teach how to use `GOTO`, it's actually a pretty good example. This might be one of the ridiculously few situations in which `GOTO` is an improvement over the alternative. Then again, just like you, I haven't used `GOTO` in production in years, so whether it even needs to be taught is questionable.

Answer (score 0):

After your comments to my previous answer, I got a better idea of your situation.

Here's what I understand so far:

- You have an exercise for a Fortran training/lessons/etc.
- The exercise is to create a program that takes as input an array of arbitrary length, and then prints out the final values of each monotonic sequence in that array. So for example, if the input were `4 3 7 2 1 4 6 3 5 10`, then the output should be something like:

  ```
  Starts with 4
  Decreases to 3
  Increases to 7
  Decreases to 1
  Increases to 6
  Decreases to 3
  Increases to 10
  The end
  ```
- Part of the exercise is that you should make use of the `GOTO` command.

So here's my updated answer:

1. This is not a homework service, we won't solve the issue for you. Then again, you didn't ask for that, so that's okay.
2. Your issue is not the `read*, ar` command. You can test this out easily by just adding a `print*, ar` right below it, it will print.
3. Your issue is that there is an infinite loop inside your code (actually, there are several), some because you use `DO WHILE` loops where the condition never changes in the iteration, some because you jump out of one loop to the beginning of another, which resets the initial conditions.

Here are some hints for your exercise:

1. Create a single variable for the index of the array that you're currently looking at.
2. Create two loops, one for increasing this index as long as the next value in the array is larger, and one as long as the next value is smaller. Check that you don't increase the index beyond the range of the array.
3. Do not jump from inside of any loop
4. Do not jump into the middle any loop.
5. At the end of either loop, think about what you learned about the array, and were to jump to from there.
6. Make sure that you know that the algorithm will eventually stop.
7. And finally, there's no harm in using lots of `print*` statements during debugging to make you understand what the program is actually doing.